# FullCalendar - Sending view via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to integrate the [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) plugin into a website. The problem I am experiencing is that I am trying to send the current view, wether it be month, agendaDay etc..., as a custom parameter via the json/$.ajax method.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: {
    url: 'feed.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        view: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
}
});
```

The above is returning any errors but the custom `view` variable is not being passed along with the normal values.

I have tried the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'feed.php?view=' + $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name,
       .......
```

But this just add `?view=undefined` to the ajax call. I know that `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name` works as it returns the correct value so it must be something with the line `view: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name` but I unsure of what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access the fullCalendar before it has been initialized.  Try breaking it into separate steps:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
var viewName = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'feed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            view: viewName
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using this method how would I update the viewName variable when the user switches view?

Comment: You'd actually have the same problem with your original code (if it worked).  The call to 'getView' is made right away, not when the ajax request is made.  I'm not familiar enough with fullCalendar to give you a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I would add my solution to this problem for future reference.

By simply determining the number of days between the `start` and `end` timestamps passed by fullCalendar to my server side php I could tell which view we were retrieving data for.

```
$NumberOfDaysInView = abs($_GET['start'] - $_GET['end'])/60/60/24;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you call "fullCalendar()" before initialized and it is not allowed to do so.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({...});
```

This means $('#calendar') (a jquery object) is going to be initialized by the values you sent in {...}.

Thus, before fullCalendar() initialization is done, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

**FullCalendar v4 and after**

```js
// import FullCalendar like so:
// import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';

// then initialize Full Calendar on your element
let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
let calendar =  new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    // all your calendar settings except the events one
});

// then add your events source and configure it to send the calendar current view
calendar.addEventSource({
    url: "/url_of_your_events",
    extraParams: function() {
        return {
            viewName: calendar.view.type,
        };
    },
});

// then render your calendar
calendar.render();
```

**FullCalendar v3 and before** using jQuery

```js
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    // all your calendar settings
    // ...

    // configure the event source to send the calendar current view
    events: {
        url: "/url_of_your_events",
        data: function() {
            return { view: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name };
        },
    },
});
```